# Numpy working in anaconda environments but not in the terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, anaconda

I have downloaded anaconda and always used Jupiter Notebook, and Spyder with no problem. Now I need to run some code on my computer's `python` shell (I don't know if this is the appropriate name, I am quite new to coding) but when trying to `import numpy` I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I have tried everything whit pip but is not resolving the problem, it actually shows a syntax error. Should I try to uninstall and install everything? I don't really know how to move, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You can check this out: https://www.edureka.co/blog/install-numpy/

Answer (score 1):

When you start a new terminal instance the base conda environment is not activated, so when you do `python`, the interpreter that is called is not Anaconda's Python, it is most likely the system-wide Python installation.

So to access Anaconda's Python from the terminal:

- `conda activate` to activate the base conda environment
- `which python` should show the path to the Anaconda interpreter
- `python`

Interactive shell:

> import numpy

Comment: You could add that the cause of the issue is that the base conda env is not activated, thus not `python` from anaconda is called, but some other python (probably system's)

Answer (score -1):

Anaconda is a virtual environment for python. It does not install packages globaly. I strongly recomend reading about VENV (virtual enviroment).

You can install does packages globally, by pip:

```
pip install numpy
```

or for python3:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but I tried those in the terminal and show syntax error

Comment: You are using ubuntu, or windows ?
Try following these: 
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-numpy

Comment: I'am using macOS

Comment: You should be able to check Your python version by typing in cmd: python -v
Also check if pip is installed by: pip -V or pip3 -V.
If it is You should be able to install numpy and other python packages by pip

Comment: This does not adress the root cause, numpy is already installed for the anaconda distribution. Installing it for the systems python will only create redundancy

Comment: Of course, preferable solution is to alway warok within venv, but comiling with shell does not need to go this way. Installing packages globally is usefull, when You need a specifin version in venv.